# Pointer to a Pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, char

I am writing a below Pro*C program and I am getting core dump error, could someone please help me what I am doing wrong. I am new to `C`

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
  char inputpath1[300]="";
  char inputpath2[300]="";
  gets(inputpath1);
  gets(inputpath2);
  ExtractCmpFiles(inputpath1,inputpath2); //contains fullpath with file
return 0;
}

void ExtractCmpFiles(char *inputpath1,char *inputpath2)
{
  int i=0;
  char *strings[2];
  strings[0]=malloc(sizeof(inputpath1)+1);
  strcpy(strings[0],inputpath1);
  strings[1]=malloc(sizeof(inputpath2)+1);
  strcpy(strings[1],inputpath2);
  printf("Your files are:\n%s\n%s\n",strings[0],strings[1]);//i am getting output here
  char **holder='\0';
  char ioarea[4096];
  for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
      inFile=fopen(strings[i],"r");
      if(!inFile)
        {
          fprintf(stderr,": Open failure for output file:");
          fprintf(stderr,strings[i]);
          fprintf(stderr,"\n");
        }
      holder=&strings[i];
      holder=strrchr(strings[i],'/');  //checking the address of '/' to get only filename
      holder++; //incrementing pointer
      printf("your holder is: %s\n",*holder);
      if(strncmp(holder,"bills",5)==0) //checking value from the pointer address is "bills" or not
        {
          //do as you wish
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
/your/path/bills.cmp
/your/path/bill.cmp
```

Thank you all. I have modified the function as per suggestions, but still I am getting core dump error
Adding modified function:

```
 void ExtractCmpFiles(char *inputpath1,char *inputpath2)
{
  char *strings[2];
  strings[0]=(char*)malloc(strlen(*inputpath1)+1);
  strcpy(strings[0],inputpath1);
  strings[1]=(char*)malloc(strlen(*inputpath2)+1);
  strcpy(strings[1],inputpath2);

  printf("Your files are:\n%s\n%s\n",strings[0],strings[1]);

  char *holder=NULL;
  char ioarea[4096];

  int i=0;

  for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
      inFile=fopen(strings[i],"r");
      if(!inFile)
        {
          fprintf(stderr,": Open failure for output file:");
          fprintf(stderr,strings[i]);
          fprintf(stderr,"\n");
        }
      holder=strings[i];
      holder=strrchr(strings[i],'/'); 
      printf("i=%d --- %s\n",i,strings[i]);   //when i=0 it is giving output then it is giving coredump
      printf("your holder1 is: %s\n",holder);
      holder++;
      printf("your holder2 is: %s\n",holder);
      if(strncmp(holder,"custbills",9)==0)
        {
          //do something
        }
      else
        {
          //do something
        }

  fclose(inFile);
}
```

Comment: Use `strlen` in the `malloc`.

Comment: You should also write `sizeof(*inputpath1)` and not `sizeof(inputpath1)`. Same for all others

Answer (score 4):

The variable `holder` is a pointer to a pointer to `char`, and you assign to it the result of [`strrchr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strrchr), a function that returns a pointer to `char`.

That will make `holder` no longer point to the array entry, so when you do `holder++` it points somewhere else completely which leads to undefined behavior when you dereference `holder`. You then continue to pass `holder` to [`strncmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncmp) which again will give you undefined behavior.

The `holder` variable is not a character either, so you should not initialize it as one. If you want to initialize it you should initialize it to point to `NULL`.

The things mentioned above should make the compiler shout warnings at you.

---

Also, as noted in a comment by Cool Guy, if you want to get the length of a string you should use [`strlen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen). When you use `sizeof` you get the size of the *pointer* and not what it points to.

Answer (score 1):

```
strings[0]=(char*)malloc(strlen(inputpath1));
strings[1]=(char*)malloc(strlen(inputpath2));
```

...

```
char *holder=NULL;
```

...

```
fclose(inFile);
```